# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: 'libqt5printsupport5:amd64':

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, upgrade, dpkg

How do I fix this problem?

When I try to get an upgrade,

`sudo apt upgrade -y`

the output will show like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  google-chrome-stable initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin
  initramfs-tools-core libapache2-mod-php7.1 libnss-myhostname libpam-systemd
  libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 libudev1 libudev1:i386 libvorbis0a
  libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvorbisfile3 nodejs
  php7.1 php7.1-bz2 php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-curl php7.1-gd php7.1-json
  php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-mysql php7.1-opcache php7.1-readline
  php7.1-xml php7.1-zip systemd systemd-sysv teamviewer udev
35 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/87.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libqt5printsupport5:amd64': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Can you please help me how to fix it without reinstall my ubuntu.

I've been read from some tutorials, tried another way but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: I/O error = dying hard drive.

Comment: You can try as first `sudo apt clean` followed by `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`. In most cases this will fix it by redownloading the data in case the file got corrupted on the way. If this not helps give please feedback.

Comment: it didn't work for me,...
after I try to 

`sudo apt clean`, 
`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`,
the output still the same error...

the following error is still there..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall this package manually:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get download libqt5printsupport5
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libqt5printsupport5*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

this will affected reinitialize *.list file in `/var/lib/dpkg`-database.

Comment: already did, but it doesn't work...

the output is :

`dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:  reading files list for package 'libqt5printsupport5:amd64': Input/output error`